# Can one quantum state describe two different scenarios?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

The wavefunction or the abstract ket vector $|\psi\rangle$ contains *all* the information about the state of the system.

Before giving more context I word my question as follows, does the information (the most we can have) contained in $|\psi\rangle$ enough to distinguish between systems?

or,

Does $|\psi\rangle$ uniquely specify a system?

Now the context,
Consider $$|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|\uparrow \downarrow\rangle-|\downarrow \uparrow\rangle)$$

This wavefunction describes the following two different scenarios(systems):

1. State of two indistinguishable electrons
2. The entangled state of an electron-positron pair.

If I were just given $|\psi\rangle$, I would now know whether the system is (1) or (2).

So it seems that $|\psi\rangle$ does not contain any information that differentiates between (1) and (2).

Comment: It is not true that the state you write describes both of these scenarios on equal footing.  Once you write a second-quantized notation (which the above is, if you even want to remotely compare the two), you talk about electronic modes rather than electrons, which are perfectly distinguishable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I were just given $|\psi\rangle$ I would not know whether the system is (1) or (2). So it seems that $|\psi\rangle$ does not contain any information that differentiates between (1) and (2).

The expression
$$|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(\left|\uparrow\downarrow\right> - \left|\downarrow\uparrow\right>\big)$$

is just a collection of pen strokes. Whatever meaning it has is in the mind of the person reading it, and needs to be specified either explicitly or via some context.  When I see that collection of symbols, my assumption is that we're considering the Hilbert space $\mathbb C^2 \otimes \mathbb C^2$, that $\left|\uparrow\right>$ and $\left|\downarrow\right>$ are shorthand for $\pmatrix{1\\0}$ and $\pmatrix{0\\1}$ in the $\hat z$-basis, and that $\left|\uparrow\downarrow\right> \equiv \left|\uparrow\right> \otimes \left|\downarrow\right>$.

The reason I am comfortable making these assumptions is because this type of notation generally has a standard meaning. However, in the absence of context I can't say anything more.  Are we modeling a system of two electrons, in which case the true Hilbert space is not the full $\mathbb C^2\otimes \mathbb C^2$ but rather only the antisymmetric subspace? Or are we modeling a system of an electron and a positron, which are distinguishable? Or are we modeling the composite spin state of an electron and an atomic nucleus?

You say "if I were just given $|\psi\rangle$ [...]." I'm afraid I don't fully know what this means.  If you just come across an expression scrawled upon a piece of paper, then it's not much more than a sequence of lines. Even the (reasonable) assumptions I make above may not be correct - for instance, one might follow that expression with

> [...] where $\left|\uparrow\right>$ and $\left|\downarrow\right>$ refer to the spin states along the $\hat x$ axis, so e.g. $\left|\uparrow\right> \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1\\1}$ in the $\hat z$-basis.

On the other hand, if you come across that expression after the author has written

> Let's consider the composite spin state (along the $\hat z$-axis) of two indistinguishable electrons given by [...]

then we can understand all of the rest of our questions in this context.

The point is that notation is not sacred and context is crucial. A single expression such as the one you've written for $|\psi\rangle$ does not have any unambiguous meaning in the absence of this context, so just writing that sequence of pen strokes does not define a state of any particular system. At minimum, I would like to know what Hilbert space that vector is an element of, and what physical system that Hilbert space is supposed to be modeling.

Comment: Consider $x(t)$ for a classical particle. In here, it doesn't matter if we are talking about the motion of a ball, a banana, or anything else, it is implicit that the trajectory followed by the COM of the thing will be specified by $x(t)$. But in the quantum case, we have two wildly different phenomena a.k.a indistinguishability and entanglement.  Let's suppose for a moment that the state to account for indistinguishability be something else my being able to write the above state would mean that a phenomenon like entanglement could exist.

Comment: @Lost My point is that you *haven't* written a state vector. You've written a sequence of (familiar) lines which you'd like the reader to *interpret* as a state vector, but haven't specified either explicitly or implicitly the rest of the information needed to understand the space in which that vector lives. As an analogy, I could ask whether $\vec x = \pmatrix{1\\2}$ lives in a 1D vector space or a 2D vector space - but in the absence of additional information, it could be either one.  You would probably *guess* the latter if you had to, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Okay so when one says "the state ket of a system completely describes the system". That is only true when we implicitly know the system we are talking about ryt? Otherwise we would need "additional info"

Comment: @Lost It would be more accurate to say that if you **don't** know what system or Hilbert space you're talking about, then the notation is meaningless. If I asked about the properties of the state vector $\left|\leftrightsquigarrow\right>$, you would pretty obviously have to ask what Hilbert space it lives in, what the notation means, etc.  The same is essentially true of the notation you are using, except for the fact that your notation is sufficiently familiar to allow the reader to make an educated guess. But that's still a guess.

Answer (score 0):

$|\psi\rangle$ is an element of some Hilbert space and part of defining that Hilbert space is specifying what physical system it describes the states of, so yes the state $|\psi\rangle$ does contain information about what physical system it describes. Having said that this particular bit of information is typically obvious from the context or, at the very least, rarely need to be specified more than once. We therefore do not clutter our notation by explicitly including it in the way we typically write the state vector.

Comment: " |ψ⟩ does contain information about what physical system it describes" How with just the state information given in the question would you be able to tell whether I am talking of an entangled electron-positron pair or a fermionic state? (without any additional info like context aka a priori knowing the system)